# ios programming using uitextview as text editor

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, text, uitextview

I'm developing an application for ipad that works like a text editor where you can input text without any limitations into a uitextview. However the problem I have is that after a while when the text gets quiet large (about 20 pages) there is big lag when entering new characters. Is this a problem related to uitextview that can't handle large texts or is this just a limitation based on ipad hardware. Should I be using something else instead of an uitextview to input text? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try to cache in and out the UITextView yourself, then it will certainly become faster. I do not know any other object that is more suitable, since all the editing methods are already there.

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell me how to do that or point me to a website that explains how to do that since I have never done anything like that.

Comment: the principle is easy - the implementation might be complex. You would keep a known portion of the text in the editable textView. The text before and after is kept in variables outside the text view. whenever you scroll up or down you have to adopt the three text portions. Searching, replacing and possibly other global operations need to consider that the complete text is composed of three parts. Depends what kind of editing the user will mainly do, this might work really well (in cases where editing is continous and local) as opposed to jumping around a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe split things up into multiple UITextViews if the text gets too long?